# Не удается в фрагменте получить методы из интерфейса. Как это можно исправить?

Tags: java, android

Почему при попытки получить методы из интерфейса, пишет `Cannot resolve method 'isProduct()'` и `Cannot resolve method 'getMenuTitle()'`.
`ourMenuItems`я прописываю как `ArrayList`

```
private final ArrayList<MenuPosition> ourMenuItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

В интерефесе все есть, однако в фрагменте все равно не получается их получить. Как это можно исправить?
Вот скрин проблемного фрагмента
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код интерфейса MenuPosition

```
public interface MenuPosition {

   public String getIcon();

   public int getId();

   public String getImageUrl();

   public String getMenuTitle();

   public boolean isProduct();
}
```

Вот код проблемного фрагмента

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(View object, int n2) {
    try {
        object = (View) this.ourMenuItems.get(n2);
        if (!object.isProduct()) {
            if (this.materialFragmentActivityCallback != null) {
                object = CatalogFragment.instance(object.getId(), object.getMenuTitle());
                this.materialFragmentActivityCallback.beginFragmentManagerTransaction((Fragment)object, true);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProductActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("PRODUCT_ID", object.getId());
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас очень странный код. Но вот если тут `object = (View) this.ourMenuItems.get(n2);` поменять `View` на `MenuPosition` - должно заработать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не работает. Как тогда получить остальные методы интерфеса, кроме int?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь переписать метод `onItemClick(View object, int n2)`, которого нет в вашем интерфейсе. Судя по [этой](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) ссылке, даже во View нет метода `onItemClick(View object, int n2)`

Далее, у вас `View object` то `View` как тут `object = (View) this.ourMenuItems.get(n2);` ,то `Fragment` как тут `(Fragment)object, true)`.

Судя по тому, что у вас оба метода из MenuPosition, а именно `isProduct()` и `getMenuTitle()` подсвечиваются красным, то вы не имплемитировали интерфейс.

Comment: однако object.getId() удалось получить

Comment: Потому что [вот](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#ids). View может иметь id, который ассоциирован с этим View

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep, покажите ваше объявление класса